# Complex Object in JAX-WS is created empty

Tags: web-services, jax-ws

I'm testing JAX-WS to access the Oracle IRM web serviecs.  I can get it to work just fine with AXIS so this isn't an Oracle problem.

What's happening is that I'm getting the following error when making the call:

```
Expected xsd:anyType - unknown type provided
```

If I look at the SOAP packet is sent I see that the owner tag is blank under JAX-WS:

```
<ns1:browseAccounts>
    <owner/>
    <accountType>All</accountType>
</ns1:browseAccounts>
```

The same piece under AXIS is this:

```
<owner xsi:type="ns1:LicenseServer" 
       xmlns="" 
       xmlns:ns1="http://www.sealedmedia.com/ls/server/schema">
    <serverKey>#############</serverKey>
</owner>
```

Obviously the owner tag is not getting properly created, this is what I'm using to create that:

```
AccountServicesPort AA = ORI.getAccountServices();
LicenseServer LicSer = new LicenseServer();
LicSer.setServerKey("#######################");
List<Account> Acts = AA.browseAccounts(LicSer,AccountAccountType.ALL);
```

Is there some other process that I need to go through to create the object properly?

**EDIT**

I thought maybe running the LicenseServer creation through ObjectFactory would help.  Unfortunately, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the Oracle IRM documentation stating that BrowseAccounts accepts either a LicenseServer object or a Context object for the owner parameter it actually accepts  an LicenseServer_ref.

**EDIT**
Further, I was running JAX-WS under JDK 1.6.0 which is a lower version than JDK 1.6.0_14.  The new version supports XMLSeeAlso annotation which allowed JAX-WS to use the proper class for serialization.